# Checking whether specific data is already in a table using SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database that I would like to check whether data has already been entered into it. The user can input their data using forms and it gets added to the table ok. However it seems as though the check isn't being made as I look on the database and can see duplicates.

Here is the check I am trying to make:

```
$sqlCheck = "SELECT ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired FROM activBooking WHERE ActivID = '$_POST[ActivID]' AND DateRequired = '$_POST[DateRequired]' AND TimeRequired = '$_POST[TimeRequired]'";

if($sqlCheck->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Sorry, this time slot is unavailable for this activity";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO activBooking (CustomerID, ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired) VALUES ('$_POST[CustomerID]','$_POST[ActivID]','$_POST[DateRequired]','$_POST[TimeRequired]')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo "Press back to return";
    } else {
        echo "Error" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

However, it looks as though the first if statement is being skipped and just continues to add data to the table regardless of it being a dupliate or not.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: execute query before $sqlCheck->num_rows using $conn->query($sqlCheck)

Answer (score 0):

**Execute Query Before Checking Number Of rows Return**

```
$sqlCheck = "SELECT ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired FROM activBooking WHERE ActivID = '$_POST[ActivID]' AND DateRequired = '$_POST[DateRequired]' AND TimeRequired = '$_POST[TimeRequired]'";

$sqlCheck = $conn->query($sqlCheck); //execute before counting num rows

if($sqlCheck->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Sorry, this time slot is unavailable for this activity";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO activBooking (CustomerID, ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired) VALUES ('$_POST[CustomerID]','$_POST[ActivID]','$_POST[DateRequired]','$_POST[TimeRequired]')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo "Press back to return";
    } else {
        echo "Error" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code.. You have not execute first query.

```html
$sqlCheck = "SELECT ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired FROM activBooking WHERE ActivID = '$_POST[ActivID]' AND DateRequired = '$_POST[DateRequired]' AND TimeRequired = '$_POST[TimeRequired]'";
$result=$conn->query($sqlCheck);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Sorry, this time slot is unavailable for this activity";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO activBooking (CustomerID, ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired) VALUES ('$_POST[CustomerID]','$_POST[ActivID]','$_POST[DateRequired]','$_POST[TimeRequired]')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo "Press back to return";
    } else {
        echo "Error" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest you. Hopefully the CustomerID is your primary key. Now just make the ActivID,DateRequired and TimeRequired as unique key.

After that just go for the following query;

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO activBooking (CustomerID, ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired) VALUES ('$_POST[CustomerID]','$_POST[ActivID]','$_POST[DateRequired]','$_POST[TimeRequired]')"
```

This will now only insert if record not exists in the table.

Now you can catch the result in php variable to check if it is inserted or not ; accordingly generate alert or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlCheck = "SELECT ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired FROM activBooking WHERE ActivID = '$_POST[ActivID]' AND DateRequired = '$_POST[DateRequired]' AND TimeRequired = '$_POST[TimeRequired]'";

$query=mysqli_query($con,$sqlChec);  //$con=your connection setting
$num=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($num > 0) {
echo "Sorry, this time slot is unavailable for this activity";
} else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO activBooking (CustomerID, ActivID, DateRequired,  TimeRequired) VALUES   ('$_POST[CustomerID]','$_POST[ActivID]','$_POST[DateRequired]','$_POST[TimeRequired]')";

if($sql){
 echo "Data Entered";
}
else{
    echo "Problem while entering new data";
}
}
```